# Having trouble creating buttons with a for-loop through tkinter. (Python)

Tags: python, button, for-loop, dictionary, tkinter

Im trying to create multiple buttons through a loop with TKinter, but when i run the script, 5 button-like objects get created, but only the last behaves as a button.With TKimage, im trying to overlay a picture that comes from an url inside a dictionary on each button. But the dictionary contains 5 images, and only the last button turns into an actual button, and has the final of the 5 images on it.

This is my code:

```
    film = films_dict['filmsoptv']["film"]                                                 #<<<< voor plaatjes films in TkinterGUI
Buttons = ['Button1','Button2','Button3','Button4','Button5']
lijstnummers = [1,2,3,4,5]
for film, i, j in zip((films_dict['filmsoptv']["film"]),(lijstnummers),(Buttons)):
    image_bytes = urlopen(film["cover"]).read()
    data_stream = io.BytesIO(image_bytes)
    pil_image = Image.open(data_stream)
    tk_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil_image)
    j = Button(window,command=close,height=296,width=200,image=tk_image)
    j.grid(row=0, column=i)
```

films_dict contains 5 sub-dictionaries which i, by calling it in a for loop, roll through to access the sub-dictionary's cover-url. The films_dict changes every day, so i can't use passive url's.

Anyone that can help me create 5 buttons instead of one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess, but I think all but the last image are [garbage collected](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm), since there is only a reference to the last image left (`tk_image` still points to that one after the loop). For some reason, the image being used in the Button, or in a Label does not count as a reference for the garbage collector. Try storing references to *all* the images in a list or dictionary, then it should work.

Also, it seems like you want to add the Button to the list `Buttons` by assigning it to `j`. This will not work, though. Better initialize `Buttons` as an empty list and `append` the new Button to that list. Try this (not tested):

```
images = []
buttons = []
for i, film in enumerate(films_dict['filmsoptv']["film"], 1):
    image_bytes = urlopen(film["cover"]).read()
    data_stream = io.BytesIO(image_bytes)
    pil_image = Image.open(data_stream)
    tk_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil_image)
    j = Button(window, command=close, height=296, width=200, image=tk_image)
    j.grid(row=0, column=i)
    images.append(tk_image)
    buttons.append(j)
```